# Releasing lock without executing a method

Tags: c#, wcf, locking

The system I am working on is composed of a Windows service hosting various WCF services. Multiple clients can talk to a same service, but only one client can talk to a service at time.
I am therefore using a "lock ()" to prevent multiple clients to conflict. If  Client1 makes a first request to a service and then Client2 makes another requested while the former is still executing, the "lock" puts that second request on hold until the first one is done.

So far so good. Now the problem is that I have to deal with events (I don't think a simple callback would do the trick here).
In other words, while the 1st request is running, something may happen that Client2 needs to know about.
When that happens, Client2 will receive that event and should eventually stop using that service all together.
The problem here is that our 2nd request is already in the locker's queue.
So how would I prevent that second request from running. Can it get cancelled?
Maybe it is just a matter of adding a dirty flag but I am hoping there are better ways to do that.
Here is what it may look like on the service side with the dirty flag "canRun":

```
lock (_locker)
{ 
    if (canRun)
       return SomeMethod();
    else
       return null;
}
```

Comment: The preferred method to cancel a process is to use a `CancellationToken`. However, you should extend your example to make your use case more clear. I don't see how events come into play here.

Comment: Thanks @PMF, it is because the clients actually needs to know what happened, but I don't think it would be responsible for cancelling the request based on that event (probably not possible)? Or maybe that is what CancellationToken is about?

Comment: Who can trigger a cancellation is up to your implementation. As said, you need to provide a bit more context.

Comment: I think you can also set the service to single thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/sessions-instancing-and-concurrency

Comment: Thanks @Ding Peng, but I do need the ConcurrencyMode set to Multiple in my case

Comment: Then this may need to use the lock you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you can switch to `async`/`await` and something like a `SemaphoreSlim`, then: `CancellationToken` is what you're looking for; a `CancellationTokenSource` can be marked as cancelled at any time, and code can respond accordingly - and most framework/library code already correctly handles cancellation, for example: during async semaphore acquisition.

If you need to stick in a synchronous world, then your best bet is probably to change to a looped `Monitor` mode that can re-check every timeout, for example:

```cs
bool lockTaken = false;
try
{
    do
    {
        if (!canRun) throw new OperationCanceledException();
        Monitor.TryEnter(_locker, someTimeout, ref lockTaken);
    }
    while (!lockTaken);
    // now we have the conch
    SomeMethod();
}
finally
{
    if (lockTaken) Monitor.Exit(_locker);
}
```

Note that if `canRun` is a field you would want to ensure that it is either `volatile` or otherwise accessed suitably to avoid being cached in a register or similar.

Comment: `lockTaken` is never updated in your example. Also, this causes busy-waiting.

Comment: @PMF oops, I missed the `ref`! fixed; and this isn't a hot loop; it is busier than the code in the question, yes, but it isn't going to sit pegging the CPU either

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is that common practice? It will get quite busy if I add that code in each API's method.

Comment: @stackMeUp I would say that the *scenario* isn't all that common, at least with `lock`; and I agree, it is messy; a `CancellationToken` would be much more convenient, but that doesn't apply to `lock`/`Monitor`

Comment: Ok, I will explore the CancellationToken option and see if I can make use of it :-)

Comment: @MarcGravell, you're right. I missed the timeout.